# Why do I get invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference?

Tags: pointers, go

I'm creating up a BST in Go, but my delete function isn't working. Can you exactly tell me where is the problem

```
func delete(d *Node, v int) {
    if v == d.key {
        fmt.Println(d.left)
        fmt.Println("Deleted")
        d = nil
    }
    if v < d.key {
        delete(d.left, v)
    }
    if v > d.key {
        delete(d.right, v)
    }
}
```

Error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x495fd0]
```

Comment: Which line is triggering the error?

Comment: if words[0] == "d" {
 delete(root, inp)
}

Comment: you probably should use `else if` here since you don't want all your predicates to get hit, either that or move your first check `v == d.key` to the bottom of the func. In . the current implementation if `v == d.key` then it gets set to `nil`, so the checks immediately after fail `if v < nil.key`

Answer (score 4):

If `d` is non-nil to begin with, and if `v == d.key`, then you set `d=nil`, and the first if statement after that will fail.

Answer (score 0):

> You can modify your function to this , i am assuming you have already
>   did the nil check i.e if d!=nil only then call delete function.

```
    func delete(d *Node, v int) {
    if v == d.key {
        fmt.Println(d.left)
        fmt.Println("Deleted")
        d = nil
        return
    }
    if v < d.key {
        delete(d.left, v)
        return
    }
    if v > d.key {
        delete(d.right, v)
        return
    }
}
```